# SassScript interactive shell doesn't work with SCSS syntax

Tags: sass

I use
`sass --scss --interactive`  or `scss --interactive` and enter 
`>> $x: 3px;`
I get the error: 
`SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "3px": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

PS: Sass installed using: `sudo gem install scss`. Then `chmod -R 755 /var/lib/gems`, followed by `chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/{scss,sass}`

Comment: It appears that the interactive only takes expressions similar to programming languages, e.g.: `3px + 3px`: it does not deal with CSS selector syntax. So you have to remove the `;`, and stuff like `width: 3px` won't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interactive shell only takes expressions similar to programming languages, e.g.:

```
3px + 3px
```

It does not deal with CSS selector or property / value syntax.

So you have to remove the `;` and write:

```
$x: 3px
```

and stuff like `width: 3px` won't work either.

This is mentioned at: http://thesassway.com/intermediate/interactive-sass-having-fun-on-the-terminal

> Sass Script is a small subset of the Sass language. It mostly includes the mathematical parts of Sass and functions. You can't use Sass features like mixins or variables.